# HTC one V is Not Connecting Via Debugger mode

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to connect "HTC one V" with my Eclipse for Android Application Testing..  I followed following steps to connect my phone.

1. Installed Google USB Driver Package..
2. From Phone Settings Debugger Mode is on in Developer Options..

But still when i try to run application in Eclipse it runs in Emulator Not in HTC device.
I deleted all Emulators but still my device is not present in connected Devices.
what should i have to do now?

Comment: check USB debugging is enabled of ur set

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

- Enable usb-debugging.
- Instal HTC phone drivers from their website.
- The next step is very important: Exit HTC sync on your pc.